# How to curl and parse endpoint data with Bash?

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to hit an endpoint `http://myapp.com/health` and get the `version` value. How would I do that? Note that I plan to run this script in TeamCity.

Response from `http://myapp.com/health`:

```
{
  "Status": "online",
  "Version": "1.23",
  "Environment": "Test"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `jq` method.

Try using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) like this:

```
curl -s 'http://myapp.com/health' | jq -r '.Version'
```

---

### Create a Bash function.

Or you can create a Bash function called `parse_json` like this; found it on this [StackOverflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26655887):

```
function parse_json()
{
    echo $1 | \
    sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g' | \
    sed -e 's/", "/'\",\"'/g' | \
    sed -e 's/" ,"/'\",\"'/g' | \
    sed -e 's/" , "/'\",\"'/g' | \
    sed -e 's/","/'\"---SEPERATOR---\"'/g' | \
    awk -F=':' -v RS='---SEPERATOR---' "\$1~/\"$2\"/ {print}" | \
    sed -e "s/\"$2\"://" | \
    tr -d "\n\t" | \
    sed -e 's/\\"/"/g' | \
    sed -e 's/\\\\/\\/g' | \
    sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//g' | \
    sed -e 's/^"//'  -e 's/"$//'
}
```

And it works like this; using inline JSON as a proof of concept:

```
parse_json '{
  "Status": "online",
  "Version": "1.23",
  "Environment": "Test"
}' Version
```

Output would be this:

```
1.23
```

---

### `awk` method.

Or this honestly this `awk` method — [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52875055/117259) — seems like the most cross-platform (at least on Unix-like systems); again using inline JSON as a proof of concept:

```
echo '{
  "Status": "online",
  "Version": "1.23",
  "Environment": "Test"
}' | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\""; RS="," }; { if ($2 == "Version") {print $4} }'
```

Comment: I got the error: `jq: command not found`. Note that I plan to run this script in TeamCity so I'm not sure if I will have `jq` available in TeamCity.,

Comment: @icu222much Well, if you can, you should install `jq`; excellent tool. But I just updated my answer with a pure Bash solution.